# D3.js--How to transition between multiple types of charts using buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, charts

I am trying learn to transition between multiple charts using buttons. Here, i want to transition between bar and scatter chart (and may be add a line chart button as well). I have been able to show respective charts by the click of the button. But, i am not able to figure out how to exit one chart when the button for the other chart is clicked and vice-versa. Following is screenshot of the interactive figure that i have created. Here, we can see that both charts show together.

[image]

Following is the data (data.csv) i am using to create the interactive chart:

[image]

Below is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Transition Scatter to Bar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" class="container">
        <h1>Transition from one chart to other</h1>
        <div id="main" role="main">
            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
                <button type="button" id="bar" class="btn btn-default">Bar</button>
                <button type="button" id="scatter" class="btn btn-default">Scatter</button>
            </div>
            <div id="vis"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="d3.v6.js"></script>
    <script src="transition.js"></script>
     
</body>
</html>
```

And the D3.js code:

```
//load data----


async function createApp(){
    const dataset= await d3.csv('data.csv')

    //create dimensions---
    let dimensions={
        width: 800,
        height:600,
        margins: {
            left: 50,
            right: 20,
            top:20,
            bottom: 50,
        },
    };

    //bound dimensions
    dimensions.boundedwidth=dimensions.width-
        dimensions.margins.left-
        dimensions.margins.right;
    dimensions.boundedheight=dimensions.height-
        dimensions.margins.top-
        dimensions.margins.bottom;


    //Draw canvas----
    wrapper=d3.select("#vis")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", dimensions.width)
        .attr("height", dimensions.height);

    bounds=wrapper.append("g")
        .style("transform", `translate(${
            dimensions.margins.left
        }px, ${
            dimensions.margins.top
        }px)`);
        
    //create scales------
    const xScatterscale= d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([0, dimensions.boundedwidth])
        .nice()        

    const yScatterscale= d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([dimensions.boundedheight, 0])
        .nice()     

    const xBarscale= d3.scaleBand()
        .range([0, dimensions.boundedwidth])
        .padding(0.2)
    
    const yBarscale=d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([dimensions.boundedheight, 0])
        .nice()

    //Draw perpherals--axes-------
    //create axis generators
    const xAxisgeneratorscatter= d3.axisBottom()
        .scale(xScatterscale)
        .ticks(8)      

    const yAxisgeneratorscatter= d3.axisLeft()
        .scale(yScatterscale)
        .ticks(9)
      
    const xAxisgeneratorbar=d3.axisBottom()
        .scale(xBarscale)

    const yAxisgeneratorbar=d3.axisLeft()
        .scale(yBarscale)

    const xAxis= bounds.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x-axis")
            .style("transform", `translateY(${
                dimensions.boundedheight
            }px)`)  
            
    const yAxis=bounds.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y-axis")

   //binding data to empty request----- 
    const requests= bounds.append("g")
            .attr("class", "request")

    const chartgroups= requests.selectAll(".request")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter().append("g")

    let duration = 750           

    const updateTransition = d3.transition().duration(duration) 
    
     scatterplot()
    
    //create functions to draw data scatter plot----
    function scatterplot(){

        const xAccessorscatter= d=> +d.risk
        const yAccessorscatter= d=> +d.return

        xScatterscale.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, xAccessorscatter)+0.05])
        yScatterscale.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, yAccessorscatter)+0.02])

        xAxis.call(xAxisgeneratorscatter)            

        yAxis.call(yAxisgeneratorscatter)
     
        const newscattergroup= chartgroups.append("circle")
            .attr("cx", d=>xScatterscale(xAccessorscatter(d)))
            .attr("cy", dimensions.boundedheight)
            .attr("r", 0)

        const scattergroups= newscattergroup.transition(updateTransition)
            
            scattergroups
                .attr("cx", d=>xScatterscale(xAccessorscatter(d)))
                .attr("cy", d=>yScatterscale(yAccessorscatter(d)))
                .attr("r", 5)
                .attr("fill", "cornflowerblue")               
                       
} 

    //create functions to draw data bar plot----
    function plotbar(){

        const xAccessorbar = d=> d.id
        const yAccessorbar = d=> +d.equity

        xBarscale
            .domain(dataset.map(xAccessorbar))
            
        yBarscale
            .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, yAccessorbar)+0.1])
      
        xAxis.call(xAxisgeneratorbar)

        yAxis.call(yAxisgeneratorbar)

        const newbarsgroups= chartgroups.append("rect")
            .attr("x", d=> xBarscale(d.id))
            .attr("height", 0)
            .attr("y", dimensions.boundedheight)
            .attr("width", xBarscale.bandwidth())

        const t= newbarsgroups
                .transition()
                .duration(duration)        
      
        t
            .attr("x", d=> xBarscale(d.id))
            .attr("y", d=> yBarscale(d.equity))
            .attr("width", xBarscale.bandwidth())
            .attr("height", d=>dimensions.boundedheight- yBarscale(yAccessorbar(d)))
            .attr("fill", "cornflowerblue")
                               
    }
 
        d3.select("#scatter").on("click", function () {
            scatterplot()
                      
          });
        
        d3.select("#bar").on("click", function () {
            plotbar()
          
          });

}

createApp()
```

I am new to d3.js and still trying to figure out the *Enter, Update, Exit* trinity. I have found some examples where button is has been used to transition/update bar charts with new data. However, i am struggling to figure out how to exit one chart when the other chart gets drawn and vice versa on the click of the button.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

UPDATE (WORKING CODE):

I was able to work out how to transition with help from some "Good" Samaritan. I thought i will share the working code here:

```
//load data----


async function createApp(){
    const dataset= await d3.csv('data.csv')

    console.log(dataset)
   
    //create dimensions---
    let dimensions={
        width: 800,
        height:600,
        margins: {
            left: 50,
            right: 20,
            top:20,
            bottom: 50,
        },
    };

    //bound dimensions
    dimensions.boundedwidth=dimensions.width-
        dimensions.margins.left-
        dimensions.margins.right;
    dimensions.boundedheight=dimensions.height-
        dimensions.margins.top-
        dimensions.margins.bottom;


    //Draw canvas----
    wrapper=d3.select("#vis")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", dimensions.width)
        .attr("height", dimensions.height);

    bounds=wrapper.append("g")
        .style("transform", `translate(${
            dimensions.margins.left
        }px, ${
            dimensions.margins.top
        }px)`);
        
    //create scales------
    const xScatterscale= d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([0, dimensions.boundedwidth])
        .nice()        

    const yScatterscale= d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([dimensions.boundedheight, 0])
        .nice()       


    const xBarscale= d3.scaleBand()
        .range([0, dimensions.boundedwidth])
        .padding(0.2)
    
    const yBarscale=d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([dimensions.boundedheight, 0])
        .nice()

    //Draw perpherals--axes-------
    //create axis generators
    const xAxisgeneratorscatter= d3.axisBottom()
        .scale(xScatterscale)
        .ticks(8)      

    const yAxisgeneratorscatter= d3.axisLeft()
        .scale(yScatterscale)
        .ticks(9)
      

    const xAxisgeneratorbar=d3.axisBottom()
        .scale(xBarscale)

    const yAxisgeneratorbar=d3.axisLeft()
        .scale(yBarscale)

//creating a group element which contains all the things related to x-axis like axis and the labels
    bounds.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x-axis")
            .style("transform", `translateY(${
                dimensions.boundedheight
            }px)`)  
        .append("text")
            .attr("class", "x-axis-label")
            .attr("x", dimensions.boundedwidth/2)
            .attr("y", dimensions.margins.bottom-10)
            .attr("fill", "black")
            .style("font-size", "1.4em")
            
//creating a group element which contains all the things related to y-axis like axis and the labels
    bounds.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y-axis")
        .append("text")
            .attr("class", "y-axis-label")
            .attr("x", -dimensions.boundedheight/2)
            .attr("y", -dimensions.margins.left+10)
            .attr("fill", "black")
            .style("font-size", "1.4em")
            .style("transform", "rotate(-90deg)")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")  
    
        

   //binding data to empty request----- 
    const requests= bounds.append("g")
            .attr("class", "request")

    const chartgroups= requests.selectAll(".request")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter().append("g")

    let duration = 750           

    //const updateTransition = d3.transition().duration(duration)  

    const updateTransition = (t) => {
        return t.duration(duration)
    }

    var previousChartType = "scatter";
     
    scatterplot();
   
    
    //create functions to draw data scatter plot----
    function scatterplot(){

        const xAccessorscatter= d=> +d.risk
        const yAccessorscatter= d=> +d.return

        xScatterscale.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, xAccessorscatter)+0.05])
        yScatterscale.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, yAccessorscatter)+0.02])

        const xAxis=bounds.select(".x-axis")
            .transition()
            .call(updateTransition)
            .call(xAxisgeneratorscatter)   
            
            
        const xAxislabel= xAxis.select(".x-axis-label")
                    .transition()
                    .call(updateTransition)
                    .text("Risk")

        const yAxis= bounds.select(".y-axis")
            .transition()
            .call(updateTransition)
            .call(yAxisgeneratorscatter)


        const yAxislabel= yAxis.select(".y-axis-label")
            .transition()
            .call(updateTransition)
            .text("Return")

        const newscattergroup= chartgroups.append("circle")
            .attr("cx", d=>xScatterscale(xAccessorscatter(d)))
            .attr("cy", dimensions.boundedheight)
            .attr("r", 0)

        const scattergroups= newscattergroup
                .transition().duration(previousChartType === "bar" ? duration : 0)
                // .call(updateTransition)
                    .attr("cx", d=>xScatterscale(xAccessorscatter(d)))
                    .attr("cy", d=>yScatterscale(yAccessorscatter(d)))
                    .attr("r", 5)
                    .attr("fill", "red")     
                    
        previousChartType = "scatter";
} 

    //create functions to draw data bar plot----
    function plotbar(){

        const xAccessorbar = d=> d.id
        const yAccessorbar = d=> +d.equity

        xBarscale
            .domain(dataset.map(xAccessorbar))
            
        yBarscale
            .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, yAccessorbar)+0.1])
      
        const xAxis=bounds.select(".x-axis")
            .transition()
            .call(updateTransition)
            .call(xAxisgeneratorbar)

        const xAxislabel=xAxis.select(".x-axis-label")
                    .transition()
                    .call(updateTransition)
                    .text("id")

        const yAxis=bounds.select(".y-axis")
                .transition()
                .call(updateTransition)
                .call(yAxisgeneratorbar)

        const yAxislabel=yAxis.select(".y-axis-label")
                .transition()
                .call(updateTransition)
                .text("Equity")

        const newbarsgroups= chartgroups.append("rect")
            .attr("x", d=> xBarscale(d.id))
            .attr("height", 0)
            .attr("y", dimensions.boundedheight)
            .attr("width", xBarscale.bandwidth())

        const t= newbarsgroups
                .transition().duration(previousChartType === "scatter" ? duration : 0)
                //.call(updateTransition)
                    .attr("x", d=> xBarscale(d.id))
                    .attr("y", d=> yBarscale(d.equity))
                    .attr("width", xBarscale.bandwidth())
                    .attr("height", d=>dimensions.boundedheight- yBarscale(yAccessorbar(d)))
                    .attr("fill", "cornflowerblue")
     
        
        const barText= chartgroups.filter(yAccessorbar)
            .append("text")
            .attr("x", d=>xBarscale(d.id)+(xBarscale.bandwidth())/2)
            .attr("y", dimensions.boundedheight)
            .transition().duration(previousChartType === "scatter" ? duration : 0)
            // .call(updateTransition)
                .attr("x", d=>xBarscale(d.id)+(xBarscale.bandwidth())/2)
                .attr("y", d=>yBarscale(yAccessorbar(d))-5)
                .text(yAccessorbar)
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("fill", "black")
                .style("font-size", "12px")
                .style("font-family", "sans-serif")       
                
        previousChartType = "bar";

    }
 
        d3.select("#scatter").on("click", function () {
            chartgroups
            .selectAll("rect")
            .attr("fill-opacity", 1)
            .transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attr("y", dimensions.boundedheight)
            .attr("height", 0)
            .attr("fill-opacity", 0)
            .remove();

            chartgroups
            .select("text")
            .transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attr("fill", "white")
            .remove();
    
            scatterplot()
                      
          });

        
        d3.select("#bar").on("click", function () {
            chartgroups
                 .selectAll("circle")
                 .attr("fill-opacity", 1)
                .transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("fill-opacity", 0)
                .remove();
                
            plotbar()
          
          });

}

createApp()
```

Following is the working example:

https://pyarasid.github.io/D3.js-Animate_MultipleCharts_Button/

Comment: If you're just starting out, you might want to consider using D3's lastest version. The new `selection.join` is an improvement over the old enter, append, merge system.

Comment: Thanks @SmokeyShakers for the suggestion. But, i think i am struggling even before in the logic and how to implement that logic. I have two functions in the .js code which create the scatter and bar plot respectively. One function runs when scatter button is clicked and other runs when bar button is clicked. I am able to figure out what to add inside scatter function (or bar function) such that when scatter button clicks then scatter function runs and creates a scatter plot but removes the bar plot which was created when bar button was clicked.